# use ng2-charts with a loader and AfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a web page which has some charts, right now I'm trying to create a loader which is very simple:

```
<div *ngIf="loading === true; else elseBlock" class="container">
  <div class="grid-pulse la-3x">
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class LoaderComponent {

  @Input() loading = true;
}
```

which only swap between a component and a loader while the flag is true and the component when it is false.

now I implemented some of the charts like this:

```
<app-loader [loading]="loading">
  <canvas
    baseChart
    #canvas
    [labels]="chartLabels"
    [datasets]="chartData"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [chartType]="chartType">
  </canvas>
</app-loader>
```

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  // ... the other stuff, scss, html
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  loading = true;
  // more
  // data
  // ....

  ngOnInit(){
    this.httpService.get('/something').subscribe(data => {
      //do something with the data
      this.loading = false; //set loader to false.
    });
  }


}
```

which work perfectly, my `loading` variable depends on a `http` request that I do, and then I change the variable to `false` and therefore my `chart` appears.

the problem is that when I change my variable to false, it starts to mount the component, but I already stopped showing the loader.... therefore I see a blank space while the chart is appearing.

so the question is:
how can I check if the chart was already mounted and created? because I don't want to show that white space (I'll show a fake loader on top while the component starts rendering, any Ideas on how to accomplish?)

I read that someway to accomplish this is with `AfterViewInit` but can I access that information with a component that is not created by me (in this case )

Answer (score 0):

The only logical reason i can think of - You are changing the loading variable to true, before the data is actually processed and passed into the array, if you are using a forEach loop consider using await or a simple for loop.

Comment: no, the data is already set, the one is taking more seconds to load is the chart, I actually tested this with fixed data and it was the same, it is creating the component when I set the flag to false, therefore it shows white for some minor time.

Comment: Do you have access to loaderComponent? since in your last sentence you said something that made me doubt.

Comment: yeah @Yoshy , as I wrote on my question, the loader was made by me, that is why I could share the code, is just that `ngIf` and the `else` block in order to display the `ng-content`

Comment: Consider using ngAfterViewInit inside LoaderComponent and changing a different boolean variable to true and then using it to display the canvas?